# Avoid refresh event in a WebBrowser control?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control, google-earth-plugin

I am using the `GEPluginControl` in `VB.NET (VS2010)`.

My app works fine. I am using the `GEWebBrowser` control (included on the `GEPluginControl`), and I am able to show the information in the `Google Earth format`.

However, I am having troubles when the `GEWebBrowser` control `Refresh` method is called. When this happens, the `GEWebBrowser` starts to fail (the earth disappears and I am not able to reload it again).

I am not calling the Refresh method explicitly. I think this method is called automatically in the following case: when the user close the window, I'm catching the event `Form_Closing`, in order to ask the user if really wants to exit. If the answer is `No`, the user will stay on the app, but the `GEWebBrowser` control appears blank!. I can hear the sound associated to the refresh method, so I think this method may be my trouble.

Here is the `Form_Closing` event code:

```
Private Sub frmPrincipal_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    If MessageBox.Show("Quit", "Really want to exit?", _
           MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.Yes Then
        'App end.
        server.Stop()
    Else
        'User decides to stay.
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Does anybody knows how to avoid the `WebBrowser` (`GEWebBrowser` in this case) to execute the `refresh` method? If anyone knows how to solve this in any other way, I would still be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this (not guaranteed to work):

```
Private Sub StopRefresh(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.ProgressChanged
    WebBrowser1.Stop()
End Sub
```